# How to install zabbix-agent from source on raspberry pi

Tags: software-installation, compiling, raspberrypi, zabbix

Im trying to install `zabbix-agent` 3.2 on Raspberry Pi running Ubuntu Mate 16.04. The version in the repo is out of date and running the `.deb` file does not work (possibly wrong architecture).

Starting with [these](https://zabbix.org/wiki/Zabbix_on_the_Raspberry_Pi_(OS_Raspbian)) instructions I have done the following:

1. [Downloaded](https://www.zabbix.com/download_sources#tab:32) source files
2. Untar into `/usr/local/src/`
3. Executed these commands:

   ```
   $ sudo ./configure --enable-agent --with-GnuTLS
   $ sudo apt-get install apt-file
   $ sudo apt-file update
   $ ./configure --enable-agent --with-GnuTLS
   $ sudo make install
   $ sudo useradd -g zabbix zabbix
   $ sudo groupadd zabbix
   ```

Currently running this:

```
sudo /usr/local/src/zabbix-3.2.11/zabbix_agentd
```

Will create the following log entry:

```
tail -f /var/log/zabbix_agentd.log
zabbix_agentd [18112]: cannot open PID file [/tmp/zabbix_agentd.pid]: [13] 
Permission denied
```

I'm sure this is a permissions issue with the directory but once I can run this without error how do I make it run as a service?

Comment: What does `stat -c %a /tmp` show? Should be 1777 for `/tmp`. What does `ls -l /tmp/zabbix_agentd.pid` show?

Comment: stat -c %a /tmp
1777
ls -l /tmp/zabbix_agentd.pid
-rw-rw-r-- 1 zabbix zabbix 4 Mar 11 10:39 /tmp/zabbix_agentd.pid

Comment: the agent starts after adjusting the permissions but how can I make it run as a service?